# Why calling Module::Refresh->refresh is redirected to Module::Refresh::CODE?

Tags: perl

```
PerlConsole::Console::interpret(/home/perlconsole-0.4/lib/PerlConsole/Console.pm:281):
281:        Module::Refresh->refresh;
  DB<5> s
Module::Refresh::CODE(0x70a340)(/home/perlconsole-0.4/depends/Module-Refresh-0.16/lib/Module/Refresh.pm:205):
205:            *$sym = sub { goto &$code };
```

Is there anyone here that can explain this?

**UPDATE**

It seems to be caused by this block:

```
BEGIN {
    no strict 'refs';
    foreach my $sym ( sort keys %{ __PACKAGE__ . '::' } ) {
    next
        if $sym eq
        'VERSION';    # Skip the version sub, inherited from UNIVERSAL
    my $code = __PACKAGE__->can($sym) or next;
    delete ${ __PACKAGE__ . '::' }{$sym};
    *$sym = sub { goto &$code };
    }

}
```

But why? what's the difference??

Answer (score 2):

If you actually had read the comment above that piece of code you would have already known the answer to your question:

```
# "Anonymize" all our subroutines into unnamed closures; so we can safely
# refresh this very package.
```

Jesse is doing some heavy wizardry there in order to make the module able to reload itself (while undefing its own public interface before the reload).

Comment: On reload, the module deletes the (named) trampolines, not the original (anonymized) subs. The originals are only deleted after the reloading, when they are garbage collected.